# Azure DevOps Permissions Audit

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a requirement from our company auditors to be able to prove who can alter code in our source repository. Is there a method of producing a report detailing permissions?

Ideally the report would show all permissions but at least it needs to show check-in permissions. Ideally the report would be standard functionality as this tends to lead to less questioning from the auditors, but if not possible then custom reports/queries would be manageable.

We're using Azure DevOps Services.

Thanks in advance
GS

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a method of producing a report detailing permissions?

I am afraid there is no such out of box method/REST API to report detailing permissions.

To get the who can alter code in our source repository, first, we need to check which groups or individuals have permission check in code one by one:

`Project Settings`->`Repos`->`Repositories`:

[image]

Then go to `Project Settings`->`Permissions`->`Repositories` and `Organization Settings`->`Permissions`, to check members for each group:

[image]

Hope this helps.